# Javascript img tag src switch function not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have a small app the uses 3 images as buttons, the images are different colors, above the image buttons there is a big pair of glasses, depending on what color button you press the color of the glasses will change to match the color of the button that was pressed. The problem is I am getting a "Cannot set src to null" error.

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vAF8S/

Here is the function

```
//Functions that change the glasses image
function changeColor(a){
    var img = document.getElementById("imgG");
    img.src=a;
}
```

Comment: Your fiddle not showing any image ??. pls put proper src

Comment: You have multiple ids `id="glasses" id="imgG"`

Answer (score 2):

you have two Id's for the  tag. you should have only one ID. change your html.

```
<section id="banner" >

        <img id="imgG" src="images/orangeG.png"><br>
        <img id="wcolorButton" src="images/whiteT.png"  />
        <img id="bcolorButton" src="images/blueT.png" />
        <img id="ocolorButton" src="images/orangeT.png"  onClick="changeColor('images/whiteG.png')" />
    </section>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vAF8S/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you are getting this error because you have applied ID twice to the same element

**use this HTML**

```
<section id="banner" >
    <img class="glasses" id="imgG" src="images/orangeG.png"><br>
    <img class="wcolorButton" src="images/whiteT.png"  />
    <img class="bcolorButton" src="images/blueT.png" />
    <img class="ocolorButton" src="images/orangeT.png"  onClick="changeColor('images/whiteG.png')" />
</section>
```